# Pandas merge giving Nan value after column rename using dataframe.column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Merging CSV file using one common column, like Vlookup. All CSV file has same column title but each CSV has data of different company. Its daily High, Low, Close etc data for different companies.

So I'm trying to rename it using dataframe.column but after rename those column gives Nan value. If i change name manually in CSV file then it works just fine so my code is correct but if I do rename of columns it all gives 'Nan'.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

df = pd.read_csv("GE.csv")

for csv in glob.glob('Output/*.csv'):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(csv)
    ticker = os.path.basename(csv).split(".")[0]
    df1.columns = ['Date', f'{ticker} Open', f'{ticker} High', f'{ticker} Low', f'{ticker} Close', f'{ticker} Adj Close', f'{ticker} Volume']
    df = df.merge(df1, on='Date', how='left')

print(df)
df.to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, I think you're just creating new columns.  To rename dataframe columns, use [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

```
df = df.rename(columns={'old_column_name_to_change':'new_column_name'})

# example
df = df.rename(columns={'Open': f'{ticker} Open', 'Low' : f'{ticker} Low'})
```

With this approach, you can just specify the names you want to change by passing them as dictionary and the order doesn't matter

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This one is causing same problem.